# Upgrading A WP7.1 Project To WP8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

So I am screwed Again. I had a WP7.1 Project and I added some of the Code for the [Pinch And Zoom Facility](http://franantares.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/windows-phone-resuming-your-app-from-the-start-screen-or-not-part-i/) 
After adding the code as said, I Started Getting this Error

```
AppManifest Validation failed. Invalid AppPlatformVersion in WMAppmanifest.xml
```

Now I checked My WPAppManifest.xml(Window Interface) and found that none of the screen resolutions is checked by default. When I tried To check(wvga) , I was shown the error

> Designer Couldnt be loaded ,Open In XML view to fix

my WPManifest looks like this(first few lines)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2009/deployment" AppPlatformVersion="7.1">
  <App xmlns="" ProductID="{60d84a47-d758-4f91-8111-0bd47bb9a6c0}" Title="Effects" RuntimeType="Silverlight" Version="1.0.0.0" Genre="apps.normal" Author="AviaryDemo author" Description="Sample description" Publisher="AviaryDemo">
    <IconPath IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">ApplicationIcon.png</IconPath>
    <Capabilities>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA" />
    </Capabilities>
    <Tasks>
      <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml"/>
    </Tasks>
```

2) I want to add [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
I am confused , how to add the point no (7) in my App.xaml which looks like this

```
<Application 
    x:Class="AviaryDemo.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"       
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:h="clr-namespace:AviaryDemo"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">

    <!--Application Resources-->
    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/AviarySDK;component/Themes/generic.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <resources:Images xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:AviarySDK.Resources;assembly=AviarySDK"  x:Key="ImageResources"/>
            <aviary:LocalizedStrings xmlns:aviary="clr-namespace:AviarySDK;assembly=AviarySDK" x:Key="LocalizedStrings" />
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>

    <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
        <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
        <shell:PhoneApplicationService 
            Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing" 
            Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
    </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>

</Application>
```

Help is needed ! Thanks Alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading a project to Windows Phone 8 means that some changes are done internally and not just in the app manifest. The sole fact that you mentioned that some errors appeared in the manifest after adding a class to the project means that probably you did something to the manifest itself.

First things first, the `ActivationPolicy` attribute is **not supported in Windows Phone 7.1**.

If you decide to upgrade a WP 7.1 project to Windows Phone 8, you need to use the built-in upgrade option:

[image]

Comment: hello Sir , I follow your blog posts . Actually I did this . No Success

Comment: I did that.Actually, I had to modify the complete WPManifest.Now I want to ask My App.XAML had <Extensions> where i had defined access in the Picture Hub and "apps.." list. Its not Supportable in WP8 .how to fix that?

Comment: Edit your post and add the exact snippet you are using.

Comment: That's a different question unrelated to the original one. Create a new SO question for that.

Answer (score -1):

Your AppPlatformVersion reads "7.1". Shouldn't be 8.0?

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2012/deployment" AppPlatformVersion="8.0">
  <DefaultLanguage xmlns="" code="en-US" />
  <App xmlns="" ProductID="{30975ea2-5c89-4e55-8d5a-a4292a6e4890}" Title="PhoneApp1" RuntimeType="Silverlight" Version="1.0.0.0" Genre="apps.normal" Author="PhoneApp1 author" Description="Sample description" Publisher="PhoneApp1" PublisherID="{7f9f8c45-61d1-486a-9d02-4d7a2f563445}">
    <IconPath IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">ApplicationIcon.png</IconPath>
    <Capabilities>
```